# how to jest.spyon on class property

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Here is my Node.js app.. one of the module I'd like to test.
The somemodule variable can be anything. I initialize it in init() method

```
//component.js
let somemodule

class MyClass {
  async init() {
    somemodule = await SM.createMyModule()
  }

  async method1() {
    try {
      let data = await somemodule.doSomething()
      return data

    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new MyClass()
```

Then here is test file

```
//test.spec.js
const myclass = require('./component')

beforeAll(async (done) => {
  await myclass.init()
  done()
}, 5000)

test.only("test", async (done) => {
  jest.spyOn(myclass, 'somemodule', 'doSomething').mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error('System error');
    });

  ... sometest ... ()
      .then((response) => {
          expect(response).toEqual(...MyClass.);
          done();
      })
      .catch((err) => { 
          done(err);
      })

}, 5000)
```

Now jest fails on jest.spyOn()....  somemodule property does not exists

Comment: Err, `somemodule` is not a child of the class.  It is used by the class, but it does not belong to it.  It is (within that file) a global variable, which is not exported.

Comment: Also it looks like you are trying to use `await` in methods that are not defined with `async`.  I would assume that is going to be a compile error.

Comment: Thank you Taplar.. 1st sorry for code part but method1 is async .. I just miss it in question. Now to make it work should I put somemodule into Class itself and make it static?

Comment: Please update your code to show what you are actually working with then.

Comment: updated. Added async

Comment: `init` is also using await and is not async

Comment: But yes, if you want the variable to belong to the class, you need to define it in the class and set it with `this.somemodule`

Comment: yes.. that works now.. Thank you Taplar